# Cache OpenStreetMap tiles with MapCache

Tags: mapserver, tile-map-service, mapcache

I'm trying to cache OpenStreetMap related tile. The corresponding server has separate data related to opeenstreetmap (http://xx.xx.xx.xx/osm). It's an XZY Tiles service. Within the mapcache.xml file I set the source type to be tms service. But when I restart my Apache service I get a message:`unknown source type tms for source osm`.

Mapcache.xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mapcache >
   <cache name="disk" type="disk">
      <base>C:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/cache/primer3/{tileset}/{z}-{x}-{y}.{ext}</base>
      <!--<symlink_blank/>-->
   </cache>

   <source name="osm" type="tms">
      <getmap>
         <params>
            <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
            <LAYERS></LAYERS>
         </params>
      </getmap>

      <http>
         <url>http://xx.xx.xx.xx/tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png</url>
      </http>
   </source>

   <tileset name="test">
      <source>osm</source>
      <cache>disk</cache>
      <grid>g</grid>
      <format>PNG</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
      <expires>3600</expires>
   </tileset>


   <default_format>JPEG</default_format>
   <service type="tms" enabled="true">
      <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
      <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
      <format>PNG</format>
      <maxsize>4096</maxsize>
   </service>
   <service type="wms" enabled="true">
   </service>
   <service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="gmaps" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="ve" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="demo" enabled="true"/>

   <errors>report</errors>
   <lock_dir>C:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp/cache/primer2</lock_dir>

</mapcache>
```

Why does it report that the unknown type is tms if it exists as a defined service?

Answer (score 2):

In the MapCache terminology, *service* refers to protocols used for querying local MapCache and *source* refers to protocols used for querying remote servers.

XZY Tiles services like OSM can be accessed by MapCache with a [REST cache configuration](https://mapserver.org/mapcache/caches.html#rest-caches). If you need to cache it locally, you can define a tileset using this REST cache, then a WMS source + cache + tileset refering to this tileset:

```xml
<cache name="remote-openstreetmap" type="rest">
   <url>http://xx.xx.xx.xx/tile/{z}/{x}/{inv_y}.png</url>
   <headers><User-Agent>mod_mapcache/1.9dev</User-Agent></headers>
</cache>
<tileset name="remote-openstreetmap">
   <cache>remote-openstreetmap</cache>
   <grid>GoogleMapsCompatible</grid>
</tileset>

<source name="openstreetmap" type="wms">
   <http><url>http://localhost/mapcache?</url></http>
   <getmap><params>
      <format>image/png</format>
      <layers>remote-openstreetmap</layers>
   </params></getmap>
</source>
<cache name="openstreetmap" type="sqlite3">
   <dbfile>/share/caches/osm/openstreetmap.sqlite3</dbfile>
</cache>
<tileset name="openstreetmap">
   <source>openstreetmap</source>
   <format>PNG</format>
   <cache>openstreetmap</cache>
   <grid>GoogleMapsCompatible</grid>
</tileset>

<service type="wms" enabled="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can read from the documentation https://mapserver.org/mapcache/config.html

> A source is a service mod-mapcache can query to obtain image data.
>   This is typically a WMS server accessible by a URL. (**There are
>   currently only WMS, WMTS and mapfile as sources**, though others may be
>   added later if the need arises, see Data Sources).

The error message is telling that "tms" type of service is not supported as a source. The documentation about how to configure the supported source types is in 
https://mapserver.org/mapcache/sources.html#mapcache-sources

You can use tms service as a source with MapProxy https://mapproxy.org/docs/nightly/sources.html.